# How to get drop down button to stay selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically what I'm trying to do is simply to make the sorting drop down button stay selected on whatever one you click on. At the moment when you click on one of the options it always goes back to "All". My html, CSS and jquery are below also See the ALL button in action here on my site: http://fireflyliving.com/properties/

jQuery/Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function($){  

    var nav = $("#catpicker");  

    nav.find("li").each(function() {  
        if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {    

            $(this).mouseenter(function() {  
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();  
            });  

            $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
            });  
        }  
    });

})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sort">
<p>only show me :</p>
<nav id="catpicker">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="allcat" class="current"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/all-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="active" class="filter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/active-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="pending" class="filter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pending-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="sold" class="filter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/sold-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>                   
    </ul>               
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.sort nav#catpicker {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
}   

nav#catpicker ul ul { 
    display:none; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
}  

nav#catpicker ul li { 
    background: #dcdbdb;
    padding: 10px;
}  

nav#catpicker ul ul li { 
    float:none;   
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) that illustrates the problem

Comment: hello, if you go to the site you'll see what I mean: http://fireflyliving.com/properties/

Comment: Please refer to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I would recommend to change this structure of your html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out folks, it was pretty easy, just a few lines of code. Sometimes the developers on here like to make things more complicated than it should me. I like to follow the KISS formula, keep it simple stupid : )

Comment: If you figured it out, post the solution so future people looking for similar solutions find it here and not a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<

```
div class="sort">
<p>only show me :</p>
<nav id="catpicker">
       <a href="#" id="allcat" class="current"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/all-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a>
                <li><a href="#" id="active" class="filter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/active-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="pending" class="filter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pending-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="sold" class="filter"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/sold-btn-small.png" width="55px" height="55px" /></a></li>
        </li>                   
    </ul>               
</nav>
```

add this to your filter class

```
.filter
{
display:none;
}
```

in your code

```
$(document).ready(function($){  

    $("#catpicker .current").mouseenter(function() {  
                $(".filter").stop(true, true).slideDown();  
            }); 
   $("#catpicker .current").mouseleave(function() {  
                $(".filter").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
            }); 
    $("#catpicker .filter").click(function() {  
                $(this).removeClass("filter").addClass("current");
            }); 

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Unfortunately Sarath that doesn't work. Thank you for your effort!